# running python3 script in command line

Tags: python-3.x, command-line, argparse

I wrote a function in python which takes `2 lists` (with the same length) and returns another list with 2 elements. the function works perfectly but I am trying to run the python script in `command line`. to do so, I want to use `argparse` module in python. I wrote the following script in python3 using the following command:

```
python3 text.py a b results
```

the script should take 3 arguments 2 lists as input and one list as output. here is the script:

```
def fun(a, b):
    a_is_greater = 0
    b_is_greater = 0
    for element_a, element_b in zip(a, b):
        if element_a > element_b:
            a_is_greater += 1
        elif element_a < element_b:
            b_is_greater += 1
    return [a_is_greater, b_is_greater]


def main():
    import argparse
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
    ap.add_argument('--list-type', type=list)
    ap.add_argument('--list-type', type=list)
    ap.add_argument('-o', '--outlist', required=True)

    args = ap.parse_args()

    results = fun(a, b)
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL)

    try:
        main()
    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno != 32:
            raise
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        pass
```

do you know how to fix it? I have tried these 2 lists: `a = [4, 5, 2]` and `b = [3, 5, 4]`. fun function in the script works perfectly for these 2 inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this better?

`python3 text.py --list1 [4,5,2] --list2 [3,5,4] -o result  # [1, 1]`

```
def main():
    import argparse

    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
    ap.add_argument('--list1', type=list)
    ap.add_argument('--list2', type=list)
    ap.add_argument('-o', '--outlist', required=True)
    args = ap.parse_args()

    results = fun(args.list1, args.list2)
    print(results)
    return results
```

Code :

```
def fun(a, b):
    a_is_greater = 0
    b_is_greater = 0
    for element_a, element_b in zip(a, b):
        if element_a > element_b:
            a_is_greater += 1
        elif element_a < element_b:
            b_is_greater += 1
    return [a_is_greater, b_is_greater]


def main():
    import argparse

    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="")
    ap.add_argument('--list1', type=list)
    ap.add_argument('--list2', type=list)
    ap.add_argument('-o', '--outlist', required=True)
    args = ap.parse_args()

    results = fun(args.list1, args.list2)
    print(results)
    return results

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL)

    try:
        main()
    except IOError as e:
        if e.errno != 32:
            raise
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

With the corrected code using `type=list`, `sys.argv` and `args` display as:

```
1353:~/mypy$ python3 stack56531390.py --list1 [4,5,2] --list2 [3,5,4] -o result
['stack56531390.py', '--list1', '[4,5,2]', '--list2', '[3,5,4]', '-o', 'result']
Namespace(list1=['[', '4', ',', '5', ',', '2', ']'], list2=['[', '3', ',', '5', ',', '4', ']'], outlist='result')
[1, 1]
```

Note that the 'lists' come in as strings.  The `list` function splits that string into a list of characters.

```
In [607]: list('astring')                                                                              
Out[607]: ['a', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
```

The fact that `fun` works for these inputs is more a coincidence, not by design.   The inputs don't match the tested: `a = [4, 5, 2]' and 'b = [3, 5, 4]`.

Look at what happens if the user puts spaces in the lists:

```
1355:~/mypy$ python3 stack56531390.py --list1 [4, 5, 2] --list2 [3,5,4] -o result
usage: stack56531390.py [-h] [--list1 LIST1] [--list2 LIST2] -o OUTLIST
stack56531390.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 5, 2]
```

or quotes to keep the spaced lists together:

```
1357:~/mypy$ python3 stack56531390.py --list1 "[4, 5, 2]" --list2 [3,5,4] -o result
['stack56531390.py', '--list1', '[4, 5, 2]', '--list2', '[3,5,4]', '-o', 'result']
Namespace(list1=['[', '4', ',', ' ', '5', ',', ' ', '2', ']'], list2=['[', '3', ',', '5', ',', '4', ']'], outlist='result')
[2, 3]
```

So while `type=list` can be made to work, it usually isn't a good choice.  Remember, the argparse `type` is a function that is given a string; it's not a type or class specifier.

If I change the two arguments to take `*` inputs of type int:

```
ap.add_argument('--list1', nargs='*', type=int)
ap.add_argument('--list2', nargs='*', type=int)

1358:~/mypy$ python3 stack56531390.py --list1 4 5 2  --list2 3 5 4 -o result
['stack56531390.py', '--list1', '4', '5', '2', '--list2', '3', '5', '4', '-o', 'result']
Namespace(list1=[4, 5, 2], list2=[3, 5, 4], outlist='result')
[1, 1]
```

Now the two inputs are normal lists of integers, not those lists of characters that include brackets and commas.  The comparison will be numeric, not lexical.